# ¿Esta bien añadir enlaces entre las preguntas en diferentes idiomas con el mismo contenido?

Tags: discusión

La comunidad de Stack Overflow en ruso [ha propuesto hacer una nueva función para relacionar las preguntas en diferentes idiomas](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431/176684), como los artículos en Wikipedia que tienen enlaces al mismo artículo en diferentes idiomas.

Esta propuesta obtuvo el soporte de la comunidad, pero nada pasó, porque requiere la ayuda de los desarrolladores de Stack Overflow, y ellos están ocupados con muchas cosas más importantes.

En vez de esperar una nueva función oficial, podríamos añadir enlaces al final de las preguntas que tienen duplicados en otros idiomas.

Se dice que es mejor pedir perdón que permiso, y por eso, como un ejemplo he añadido enlaces al final de las preguntas siguientes:

- [¿Qué significa “use strict”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2184/416)
- [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/546661)
- [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/176684)

Hay muchas preguntas en diferentes idiomas con el mismo contenido. ¿Qué piensan ustedes, está bien relacionarlas con enlaces?

---

En otros idiomas: [English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316884/546661) • [Русский](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2541/176684)

Comment: Esta petición debería hacerse en http://meta.stackexchange.com/, dado que sería beneficiosa para las comunidades de los otros idiomas también.

Comment: @Konamiman Pues por el momento el único sitio de Stack Exchange en diferentes idiomas es Stack Overflow, y tal vez las comunidades en los diferentes idiomas tendrán opiniones diferentes. Ya he publicado en ruso e inglés, pero, desafortunadamente, no hablo portugués o japonés.

Comment: Lastimosamente, el mundo del software posee gran contenido en idioma inglés. Proponer o restringir publicar contenido que sea solo en un idioma en particular significaría que (muy posiblemente una gran) parte de ese contenido en inglés deba ser traducido y almacenado en algún lugar. No sé si cada sitio de stackoverflow en el idioma X sea el lugar adecuado para esto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `Proponer o restringir publicar contenido que sea solo en un idioma` ¿Qué? No lo estoy proponiendo. Estoy proponiendo que haya enlaces entre si mismos. Si hay contenido en más idiomas es mejor, no peor.

Comment: En teoría sí. En la práctica, no sé. Suena bonito y todo hasta que la fuente en su idioma original (no necesariamente inglés) cambie y los demás artículos en los idiomas X deban actualizarse o por lo menos colocar una nota de actualización.

Comment: Mejor si los enlaces están en español, o preferentemente en inglés, pero si tiene el mismo contenido no es necesario..

Answer (score 1):

A mí me agrada la idea de que una publicación incluya enlaces a otras similares distintos idiomas sin embargo creo que esto debe hacerlo sólo el autor de la misma.

Answer (score -1):

En general, no lo hagas. Si la pregunta o respuesta es una traducción de otra, un enlace es necesario, pero en general será raro que alguien llegue a una pregunta en un idioma que no sea el suyo, porque los buscadores como google ya discriminan por idioma.

Al final, es sólo texto extra en la pregunta que a casi nadie le servirá de nada, mejor evitarlo.